# CLI Porting error : Attempted to load a binary with incorrect format

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli, clr, 32bit-64bit

I am porting my entire projects from 32 bit to 64 bit . But after porting when i start the application i get the error as "BadImageFormat" exception . The problem is when my c# application tries to load my CLI application "MyCLI.DLL". I did not change any project settings and the same CLI works well in 32 bit . I see that the crash occurs in the constructor class when a String^ is converted to std::String. CLI class inturn calls the CPP classes.

```
std::string managedToStdString(System::String ^ str)
{
  char* cStr = (char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(str).ToPointer();
  std::string result(cStr);
  Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr(cStr));
  return result;
}
```

The result value is used to new another class which is a normal CPP class built in 64 bit.
Crash occurs in the part where this converted string is passed to another cpp class

```
MyClass* m_myCLLObject = new myCPPClass(managedToStdString(str)); ->Tried to load a binary with incorrect format
```

Comment: All C++ projects need to be compiled to the architecture matching the main EXE project, either 32-bit or 64-bit.  C++ (including C++/CLI) projects aren't AnyCPU... and you cannot load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process.